# Prove this by inequality with four variables inequality

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $a,b,c,d>0$ show that
$$\color{blue}{\left(\dfrac{a^2}{b}+\dfrac{b^2}{c}+\dfrac{c^2}{d}+\dfrac{d^2}{a}\right)^2\ge 4(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)+\dfrac{8}{3}[(a-b)^2+(a-c)^2+(a-d)^2+(b-c)^2+(b-d)^2+(c-d)^2]}$$

**By Now, I claim prove that**
$$\color{red}{\left(\dfrac{a^2}{b}+\dfrac{b^2}{c}+\dfrac{c^2}{d}+\dfrac{d^2}{a}\right)^2\ge 4(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)}\tag{1}$$
Proof:By $\color{red} {Holder}$ inequality we have
$$\left(\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{a^2}{b}\right)^2(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2d^2+d^2a^2)\ge (a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^3$$
and Note
$$a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2d^2+d^2a^2=(a^2+c^2)(b^2+d^2)\le\dfrac{(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)^2}{4}$$
so $(1)$ prove by Done !

Comment: It seems that $$\left(\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{d}+\frac{d^2}{a}\right)^2\geq13(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)-6(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)$$ is also true

Comment: To Michael Rozenberg: Try $a=4, b=3, c=2, d=2$?

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

A possible way is as follows. We use the Buffalo Way. WLOG, assume that $d = \min(a,b,c,d)$.
Let $c=d+s, \ b = d+t, \ a = d+r; \ s, t, r \ge 0$.
We have $\mathrm{LHS} - \mathrm{RHS} = a_8d^8 + a_7d^7 + \cdots + a_1d + a_0$. 
To prove (or disprove) that $a_i\ge 0$ for $i=0, 1, 2, \cdots, 8$.
I verified all $a_i$'s by SOS (Sum of Squares) numerical software.

**Previously written**

This is not an answer. I want to discuss the relationship between two inequalities.
Refer to this link [How to prove $\frac{1}{4}(\frac{a^2}{b}+\frac{b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2}{d}+\frac{d^2}{a})\ge \sqrt[4]{\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4}{4}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/852070/how-to-prove-frac14-fraca2b-fracb2c-fracc2d-fracd2a)

Let $a, b, c, d > 0$. Prove that
$$\left(\dfrac{a^2}{b}+\dfrac{b^2}{c}+\dfrac{c^2}{d}+\dfrac{d^2}{a}\right)^2\ge 4(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)+\dfrac{8}{3}[(a-b)^2+(a-c)^2+(a-d)^2+(b-c)^2+(b-d)^2+(c-d)^2], \qquad (1)$$
$$\frac{a^2}{b} + \frac{b^2}{c} + \frac{c^2}{d} + \frac{d^2}{a} \ge 4\sqrt[4]{\frac{a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4}{4}}.\qquad\qquad\qquad (2)$$

(1) is stronger than (2) since
\begin{align}
&\Big(4(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)+\dfrac{8}{3}[(a-b)^2+(a-c)^2+(a-d)^2+(b-c)^2+(b-d)^2+(c-d)^2]\Big)^2\\
&\qquad- 64(a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4)\\
=\ & \frac{16}{9} z^TQz\\
\ge\ & 0
\end{align}
where
$$z = \left(\begin{array}{c} { {a}}^2\\  {a}  {b}\\ { {b}}^2\\  {a}  {c}\\  {b}  {c}\\ { {c}}^2\\  {a}  {d}\\  {b}  {d}\\ {c} {d}\\ { {d}}^2 \end{array}\right), \quad Q = \left(\begin{array}{cccccccccc} 45 & -36 & -4 & -36 & 25 & -4 & -36 & 25 & 25 & -4\\ -36 & 186 & -36 & -45 & -45 & 25 & -45 & -45 & 16 & 25\\ -4 & -36 & 45 & 25 & -36 & -4 & 25 & -36 & 25 & -4\\ -36 & -45 & 25 & 186 & -45 & -36 & -45 & 16 & -45 & 25\\ 25 & -45 & -36 & -45 & 186 & -36 & 16 & -45 & -45 & 25\\ -4 & 25 & -4 & -36 & -36 & 45 & 25 & 25 & -36 & -4\\ -36 & -45 & 25 & -45 & 16 & 25 & 186 & -45 & -45 & -36\\ 25 & -45 & -36 & 16 & -45 & 25 & -45 & 186 & -45 & -36\\ 25 & 16 & 25 & -45 & -45 & -36 & -45 & -45 & 186 & -36\\ -4 & 25 & -4 & 25 & 25 & -4 & -36 & -36 & -36 & 45 \end{array}\right).$$